# How to parse out unwanted text in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab articles and headlines, but there's a portion I just have no idea to parse out.

```
url = "http://insideevs.com/"
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
latest = []
b = soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile("content"))
for a in b:
    latest.append(a.get_text(strip=True))
```

For example, all the items in the list have a timeframe and # of comments attached to the article. "2 weeks ago, 574 comments", etc. Can someone please advise how I can exclude these last snippets?

Comment: For each item you want the title and the abbreviated text?

Comment: @BillBell Title would be great. What did you mean by abbreviated text?
Is there also way to perhaps extract the direct link separately? (Sorry, a Python newbie here!)

Comment: Abbreviated text: the words that appear to the right of the thumbnail image terminated with '...'. Yes, you can also get the link to the full article.

Answer (score 0):

Use `extract` to remove the desired tag.

Example from your code:

```
for a in b:
    a.find('p', {"class" : "details"}).extract()
    latest.append(a.get_text(strip=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

First use BeautifulSoup to get the collection of `h3` elements that have, or are adjacent to, the data items you want. I say adjacent to because one of them the abbreviated text is a sibling of `h3` in each case.

Now from the `h3` item you can use the `select` method again to find the `a` link element inside it and to get its `text`. The text you want is a sibling of the link element; however, it's only one of several and therefore I use `:nth-of-type(1)` to request the first. Almost forgot `~ p` says, 'give me the sibling of' whatever I was called with which happens to be an `h3`.

Then we can get the link to the full article by asking for the `href` attribute of the link where before we had asked for its `text`.

I put all of this in an `enumerate` so that I could neatly arrange to truncate the output to five items from the page.

```
>>> import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> page = requests.get('http://insideevs.com/').content
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> for i, item in enumerate(soup.select('article div h3')):
...     title = item.select('a')[0].text
...     text = item.select('~ p:nth-of-type(1)')
...     url = item.select('a')[0].attrs['href']
...     if i < 5:
...         title
...         text[0].text
...         url
...         
'Plug-In Volvo XC60 T8 Enters U.S. Next Month With 10.4 kWh Battery'
'Volvo latest plug-in hybrid, the\xa0premium mid-sized SUV XC60 T8 Twin Engine, debuted in March at the Geneva Motor Show. The car is based on the company’s\xa0SPA vehicle architecture, first used in the 90 series (XC90 and S90). Production of the XC60 actually began in mid-April at the Torslanda Plant in…'
'http://insideevs.com/plug-in-volvo-xc60-t8-enters-u-s-next-month-with-10-4-kwh-battery/'
'Examining Tesla Model 3 Production Goals – Are Targets Even Feasible?'
'Tesla CEO Elon Musk notes a potential of factory production speed improvement by a factor of 10. Where does this put Model 3 production, and at what point might Tesla achieve this monumentally lofty goal? The real answer may be “never”, that is until Tesla has more than a single…'
'http://insideevs.com/examining-tesla-model-3-production-goals/'
'All-Electric Class 5 Work Truck With 100 Miles Range To Arrive This Fall'
'Chanje is a new company based out of Los Angeles,\xa0California, that intends to introduce an all-electric medium-duty vehicle on a mass scale in the U.S., promising first deliveries in 2017. The company is related to Hong Kong based FDG Electric Vehicles, which together with other partners have reportedly invested nearly…'
'http://insideevs.com/all-electric-class-5-work-truck-with-100-miles-range-to-arrive-this-fall/'
'Volkswagen CEO Admits Tesla Has Abilities It Lacks'
'It seems Volkswagen CEO Herbert Diess isn’t quite sure what to say about Tesla. About a month ago, we shared that Diess (whose personal car is a VW eGolf) believes Volkswagen can stop Tesla. His reasoning behind the statement was simply\xa0VW has abilities that Tesla doesn’t possess. Of course, this…'
'http://insideevs.com/volkswagen-ceo-admits-tesla-ahead/'
'Tesla Model 3 Sighting In New Zealand – Video'
'It’s winter over there, so why not conduct some winter testing? This isn’t the first time we’ve seen a Model 3 in New Zealand and likely won’t be the last. Imagine being in New Zealand and spotting a Model 3 prior to anyone outside of the U.S. That’s brag-worthy for…'
'http://insideevs.com/tesla-model-3-sighting-new-zealand-video/'
```